# Simple C program, error at execution with dev c++

Tags: c

The assignment: write a program that reads from the user the number of seconds and returns the maximum number of hours , minutes and seconds. (example 9954 means cu 2 hours, 45 minutes şi 54 seconds)

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
int secunde1,secunde2,minute,ore;            /* secunde1= number of seconds entered
printf("Introduceti numarul de secunde:\n"); /*"Enter the number of seconds"
scanf("%d",secunde1);                        /*reads number of seconds from input


secunde2 = secunde1%60;          /*forumla for seconds (second1 = number of seconds entered)     

minute = secunde1/60;            /*formula for a minute
ore = minute/60;                 /*formula for one hour


printf("%d secunde inseamna %d ore , %d minute si %d secunde", secunde1 , ore , minute , secunde2);

/*" x seconds mean x hours, x minutes and x secods"

}
```

I've tried a lot of things and dev c++ gives me an error after i enter the number of seconds into the window . (i have to use dev C++ for class).

I need to make this work in dev C++ 5.7.1.

Comment: First, make your C code working with a better and more recent compiler (like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) which could give you warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and be debugged with a debugger (`gdb`). once it is running well, compile with your ancient dev c++ compiler (used in C mode). Read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html); you should test its result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your

```
    scanf("%d",secunde1);  

    scanf("%d",&secunde1);
```

on a different note
your main function should be 
int main(void)
and your comment blocks are all left open. Alot of compilers will not accept that, you might want to change your comment style to

```
 //mycomment
```

or

```
/* my comment */
```

by the way you might want to change your math functions to something like

```
    secunde2 = secunde1%60;          /*forumla for seconds (second1 = number of seconds entered)*/
    ore = secunde1/3600;                 /*formula for one hour*/
    minute = secunde1/60 - ore*60;
```

to get your desired output for larger numbers

Comment: Damn, was tired and didn't see that. Thanks alot.

Comment: And if using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` you would be given a warning by the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler about your mistake. So you really need to use a better compiler.

Comment: Thanks, also saw that it gave output for minutes out of the 0-60 range, fixed that.

Comment: You will find C is a very **exact** language -- no tricks. That is one of its greatest strengths. While other languages may allow somewhat 'loose syntax', C doesn't. That means a lot of times you just need to slow down a little bit and validate your code with the **man page** or a **credible reference** (not just an "I found it on the internet reference"). The more you do, the more you appreciate what C does.